# Load a page specified by a query at log in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want different user types to see different index pages when they log in. I have put the page that they should see in the homepage column of the usertype table. I thought that the following part of the script would do that for me but it just remains on the login_action.php page. I cant figure out how to de-bug it. Would mysqli error or die work? If so where would I put it?

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, "select users.userid, users.usertypeid, usertype.homepage from users  INNER JOIN usertype ON users.usertypeid = usertype.usertypeid  WHERE users.username = '$input1';") or die(mysqli_error ($dbc)) ;
  # On success set session data and display logged in page.
  if ( $check )  
  {
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
  {
    # Access session.
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[ 'userid' ] = $row1[ 'userid' ] ;
    $_SESSION[ 'username' ] = $data[ 'username' ] ;
    $_SESSION[ 'usertypeid' ] = $row1[ 'usertypeid'];
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); 
    $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 30000;
    $_SESSION['homepage'] = $row1['homepage'];
    load ($row1['homepage']) ;
}
  }
```

The full php files are as follows (minus the header that is included on every page and includes the database connection which is working fine):

Login.php

```
<?php 

# Display any error messages if present.
if ( isset( $errors ) && !empty( $errors ) )
{
 echo '<p id="err_msg">Oops! There was a problem:<br>' ;
 foreach ( $errors as $msg ) { echo " - $msg<br>" ; }
 echo 'Please try again or email support for help</p>' ;
}
?>

<!-- Display body section. -->
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="login_action.php" method="post">
<p>User Name: <input type="text" name="username"> </p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Login" ></p>
</form>

</div>
```

login_action.php

```
<?php # PROCESS LOGIN ATTEMPT.

# Check form submitted.
if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' )
{

//open the database connection
include'connect_db.php';
$input1 = $_POST['username'];

  # Get connection, load, and validate functions.
  require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ;

  # Check login.
  list ( $check, $data ) = validate ( $dbc, $_POST[ 'username' ], $_POST[ 'password' ] ) ;

$result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, "select users.userid, users.usertypeid, usertype.homepage from users  INNER JOIN usertype ON users.usertypeid = usertype.usertypeid  WHERE users.username = '$input1';") or die(mysqli_error ($dbc)) ;
  # On success set session data and display logged in page.
  if ( $check )  
  {
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
  {
    # Access session.
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[ 'userid' ] = $row1[ 'userid' ] ;
    $_SESSION[ 'username' ] = $data[ 'username' ] ;
    $_SESSION[ 'usertypeid' ] = $row1[ 'usertypeid'];
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); 
    $_SESSION['expire_time'] = 30000;
    $_SESSION['homepage'] = $row1['homepage'];
    load ($row1['homepage']) ;
}
  }
  # Or on failure set errors.
  else { $errors = $data; } 

  # Close database connection.
  mysqli_close( $dbc ) ; 
}

# Continue to display login page on failure.
include ( 'login.php' ) ;

?>
```

login_tools.php

```
<?php # LOGIN HELPER FUNCTIONS.

# Function to load specified or default URL.
function load( $page = 'login.php' )
{
  $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . dirname( $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ) ;
  # Remove trailing slashes then append page name to URL.
  $url = rtrim( $url, '/\\' ) ;
  $url .= '/' . $page ;
  # Execute redirect then quit.
  header( "$url" ) ;
  exit() ;
}

# Function to check email address and password. 
function validate( $dbc, $username = '', $password = '')
{
  # Initialize errors array.
  $errors = array() ; 

  # Check username field.
  if ( empty( $username ) ) 
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your username.' ; } 
  else  { $u = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $username ) ) ; }

  # Check password field.
  if ( empty( $password ) ) 
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your password.' ; } 
  else { $p = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $password ) ) ; }

  # On success retrieve user_id, user_name from 'users' database.
  if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
  {
    $q = "SELECT userid, username FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND pass=SHA1('$p')" ;  
    $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) or die(mysqli_error ($dbc))  ;
    if ( @mysqli_num_rows( $r ) == 1 ) 
    {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ;
      return array( true, $row ) ; 
    }
    # Or on failure set error message.
    else { $errors[] = 'Username and password not found.' ; }
  }
  # On failure retrieve error message/s.
  return array( false, $errors ) ; 
}
```

Comment: Remove first the semi-colon (`;`) in your query inside `$result1` (`'$input1';"`).

Comment: Hi. I've tried that and it still doesn't load. I've put an echo statement in before the load command to check that it is pulling the homepage from the database and it is so it's just the load statement itself that doesn't seem to be working .

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your query in a separate string and then running it. This will help you find an error.

```
$query = "select users.userid, users.usertypeid, usertype.homepage from users  INNER JOIN usertype ON users.usertypeid = usertype.usertypeid  WHERE users.username = '$input1';";
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if (!$result1) die("Tried executing: " . $query . ", but got error: " .   mysqli_error($dbc));
```

I would then take the printed query and manually enter it in a mysql console or in Phpmysql SQL box to see where exactly the problem was.